# Create Plotly plot for each column in df with a 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I want to make multiple Plotly Scatter plots (one for each column) in a df using a `for` loop in Python. I also want to be able to show the plots by entering the column name.

See sample code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'C': [2, 1, 6, 3]})
df

     A    B    C
0    3    5    2
1    1    6    1
2    2    7    6
3    3    8    3
```

The closest I got is this:

```
for i in df.columns:
i = px.scatter(df,
               x="A",
               y=i)
```

But this fails to assign a value to each plot. I want to be able to show the plot for column A by entering A, and the plot for B by entering B, etc.

Comment: It is not clear to me what really you want. You can add the plots to a dict like `plots = {i: px.scatter(df, x="A", y=i) for i in df.columns}` and then you can show each plot with `plots['A']`, `plots['B']` and `plots['C']`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. Your solution worked as I wanted it to. If you write it as answer I will accept it:) Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the plots to a dict like

```
plots = {i: px.scatter(df, x="A", y=i) for i in df.columns}
```

which is equivalent but shorter than

```
plots = {}
for i in df.columns:
    plots[i] = px.scatter(df, x="A", y=i)
```

and then you can show each plot with `plots['A']`, `plots['B']` and `plots['C']`